# python replace multiple values from all columns in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, replace, multiple-value

Below is a sample of my table.

[image: DataFrame]

Below is the code for the table:

```
d = {'1978': ['10k', '20000'],
    '1979': ['30k', '2M'],
    '1980': ['60000', '20k'],
    '1981': ['10000', '1M'],
    '1982': ['15000', '70k'],
    '1983': ['12k', '8M']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Actually, the one I am working has 60 columns and 200 rows. However, It's the same structure.

My goal is to replace "k" for "000" and "M" for "000000" for all the rows of the many columns.

So the output should be:

[image: Expected DataFrame]

If someone could share with me the code to get this desired output, I would really appreciate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with a dictionary as argument and `regex=True`:

```
new_df = df.replace({'k':'000', "M": "000000"}, regex=True)
```

Comment: Omg!! Thanks really much , It worked!! I really appreciate! thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Hi a quick solution is to convert the columns to string, do the character replacement and then convert back to int or float. This can be done columns by column:

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'1978': ['10k', '20000'], '1979': ['30k', '2M'], '1980': ['60000', '20k'], '1981': ['10000', '1M'], '1982': ['15000', '70k'], '1983': ['12k', '8M']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = (
        df[col].astype(str)
        .str.replace("k", "000")
        .str.replace("M", "000000")
        .astype(int)
    )
```

or as a whole:

```py
df = (
   df.astype(str)
   .str.replace("k", "000")
   .str.replace("M", "000000")
   .astype(int)
)
```

Comment: Hi, Serg!! I actually was trying to to exact this code!! thanks so much for your time and attention, it worked!! thankss